# Does $\{f_n\}$ converge uniformly on $(0,1) $ and $(0,\infty)?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Let $g_n(x)=\sin^2(x+\frac{1}{n}),x\in (0,\infty)$
>   and $f_n(x)=\int _0^x g_n(t) dt$.
>
> Then show that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $(0,1)$.
>   Does $\{f_n\}$ converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)?$.

$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int _0^x g_n(t) dt=\int _0^x\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin ^2(t+\frac {1}{n})=\int_0^x \sin^2 t$ [Since $\int$ and $\sin^2x$ are continuous functions].

Hence $f(x)=\int _0^x \sin ^2 t dt$.

Now $\sup_{(0,\infty)} |f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{(0,\infty)}|\int _0^x \{\sin ^2(t+\frac{1}{n})-\sin^2 t\}|\le \sup_{(0,\infty)} \int _0^x |\{\sin ^2(t+\frac{1}{n})-\sin^2 t\}|$

Taking $|\{\sin ^2(t+\frac{1}{n})-\sin^2 t\}|=|\sin (t+\frac{1}{n})-\sin t||\sin (t+\frac{1}{n})+\sin t|\le 2\frac{1}{n}$

Hence $\sup_{(0,\infty)} |f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \sup_{(0,\infty)} 2\frac{x}{n}$

Hence if $x\in (0,1)\implies  \sup_{(0,\infty)} |f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \frac{2}{n}\to 0$

Hence $f_n$ converges uniformly on $(0,1)$.

But $f_n$ does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ because I can choose $x$ quite large such that $\frac{x}{n}>1$.

Please validate.

Comment: Your proof that $f_n$ converge uniformly on $(0,1)$ is right. But for $f$ not cenverge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ you cannot use the estimate above since you have to prove that $\sup_{(0,\infty)}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq c>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative way. In order to avoid integration, note that
$$f_n(x)-f(x)=
\int_{1/n}^{x+1/n} \sin^2(t) \, dt-\int_0^x \sin^2(t) \, dt=
\int_{x}^{x+1/n} \sin^2(t) \, dt-\int_0^{1/n} \sin^2(t) \, dt$$
Hence for $x\geq 0$,
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \int_{x}^{x+1/n} 1 \, dt+\int_0^{1/n} 1 \, dt= \frac{2}{n} $$ 
which implies that $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $[0,+\infty)$.
The same argument works if we replace $\sin(x)$ with any bounded continuous function in $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @RRL I was trying to answer to the OP's question "Can you do it without doing the integration?". I am sorry that you are disappointed.

Comment: I'm not disappointed and I'll upvote you but I wouldn't do this.

Comment: @RRL Sorry, but I do not see much difference between your answer (+1)  and mine.

Comment: Its OK.  I was heading to that in edit after OP objected to seeing the integrals computed but you were too fast.  I try to get OP to contribute on this type of question.  It's becoming less common but I always thought we were supposed to do that. I was going to make the point that $\int_0^x \cos(2 t) \, dt$ is bounded independent of $x$ which is the crux of the argument.  You are a very excellent contributor to this site.

Comment: I really liked the process

Comment: RRL I agree with you. Giving a great hint is an art form. Unfortunately, one can spend time crafting a good hint and then 15 minutes later have some bull in the china shop give a complete (and often inferior)  solution.

Comment: @RobertZ That's a good solution and it shows the same result holds for any bounded continuous function

Comment: +1  for beautiful answer @RobertZ  ...i have  one doubt how  can i show that {fn}  converges pointwise to a function on [0,∞) ? Can u give me some hints ?

Comment: I defined $f(x):=\int_0^x \sin^2(t)dt$. In my proof I show that $(f_n)_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly, therefore it converges to $f$ pointwise too.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\int_0^x \sin^2(t +1/n) \, dt = \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{4}\sin(2x+2/n) + \frac{1}{4} \sin (2/n),$$

and

$$\int_0^x \sin^2(t) \, dt = \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{4}\sin(2x) .$$

Hence,

$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leqslant \frac{1}{4}\left|\sin(2x+2/n) - \sin(2x) \right|+ \frac{1}{4} |\sin(2/n)| \leqslant \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{4}|\sin(2/n)|$$

We have uniform convergence on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Well and fine; I have seen this answer of yours before too.

Comment: Can you do it without doing the integration

Comment: @RishabhPant: Yes I can

Comment: Why did you not mention that as you included an erroneous proof of non-uniform convergence?

Comment: It will be great if you can point out my flaw and suggest an alternative in my technique

Comment: Ummm.. True should have done that

Comment: The flaw was mentioned in the comment. Bounding $\sup|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \sup(2x/n)$ would fail to prove non-uniform convergence in any case. You need the reverse inequality.  As to the proof without integration ...

Comment: Now that it's shown to be uniform convergence in the way stated how to show it without doing the integration,Any take on that

Comment: You should accept Robert Z's answer.

Comment: I also feel the same